# how to extend a LVM from disk?

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to extend the LVM from disk /dev/xvdb which has 400GB of storage and LVM has used only 240gb. But pvs and lvs showing only 10gb free. Could anyone please guide me, how to perform this task.

[image]

Comment: What's the distribution and kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do it to execute command

```
pvresize /dev/xvdb
```

This will extend the physical partition to the new size of disk xvdb. And this will follow extend the volume group.

Comment: Don’t forget to resize fs afterwards…

Comment: @karlsebal, right, but after extend LV :)

Comment: Thank you guys :) task accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to resize your physical volume

```
pvresize /dev/xvdb
```

and second is to extend your logical volume

```
lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE /dev/xvdb
```